# yq add property to object somewhere in the tree

Tags: yaml, openapi, yq

I'm trying to add a response to all objects with the key `responses` in an open api yaml file. I tried a lot and failed hard because I think I miss some basic understanding but I don't know what exactly.

**File**

```
openapi: 3.0.1
info:
  title: my service
  description: API for my service
  version: 1.0.0
security:
  - jwt:
    - read
paths:
  '/foo/{fooId}/firmware/update-request':
    post:
      parameters:
        - name: fooId
          in: path
          description: Foo Id
          required: true
          schema:
            type: string
      requestBody:
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              $ref: '#/components/schemas/FooRequest'
            example:
              firmwareVersion: "0.1"
      responses:
        '202':
          description: Foo has been done
        '400':
          $ref: '#/components/responses/BadRequest'
        '409':
          $ref: '#/components/responses/Conflict'
        '401':
          $ref: '#/components/responses/Unauthorized'
        '403':
          $ref: '#/components/responses/Forbidden'
        '404':
          $ref: '#/components/responses/NotFound'
        '500':
          $ref: '#/components/responses/ServerError'
        '502':
          $ref: '#/components/responses/BadGateway'
  '/foo/{fooId}/firmware/auto-update':
    put:
      parameters:
        - name: fooId
          in: path
          description: Foo Id
          required: true
          schema:
            type: string
      requestBody:
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              $ref: '#/components/schemas/FooUpdate'
            example:
              enabled: true
      responses:
        '204':
          description: Foo update
        '400':
          $ref: '#/components/responses/BadRequest'
        '401':
          $ref: '#/components/responses/Unauthorized'
        '403':
          $ref: '#/components/responses/Forbidden'
        '404':
          $ref: '#/components/responses/NotFound'
        '500':
          $ref: '#/components/responses/ServerError'
        '502':
          $ref: '#/components/responses/BadGateway'
   # goes on forever
```

Goal is that every response looks like

```yaml
responses:
  '204':
    description: Foo update
  # ...
  'xxx':
    description: yyy
```

**while keeping the file structure intact.**

What I tried:

```
yq -i '.. | select(has("responses")).responses | . += {"xxx": {"description": yyy}}' my.yaml
```

This was the idea, that came the closet my my expected result. But now every node from root to responses are missing.
What is the correct syntax to tell yq *"Do this transformation in place on every node with this name without knowing it's level and without affecting every other node"*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were almost there. Just wrap the whole search on the LHS into parentheses to eventually retain the outer context:

```bash
(.. | select(has("responses")).responses) += {"xxx": {"description": "yyy"}}
```

Note: I have also wrapped `yyy` in quotes and simplified `| . +=` to just `+=`.

You could also just set the `xxx` field directly:

```bash
(.. | select(has("responses")).responses).xxx = {"description": "yyy"}
```

Both of these assume to be executed with [mikefarah/yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq). For a [kislyuk/yq](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq) solution, add a `?` to get `has("responses")?` as `..` will also capture non-objects.

This was tested on [mikefarah/yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq) version 4.20.2, and on [kislyuk/yq](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq) version 3.0.2.

Comment: Thanks it works. Is there any documentation on the `()` behavior? I couldn't find it.

Comment: @Sven I'll see if I can find something. But I guess it's rather the documentation of `|` telling you that it changes the context (referenced by `.`). Using `()` around some expression(s) just encapsulates that branch, regardless of its context being changed or not.

Comment: @pmf. Please reference the yq version you are using in the answer, though it is explicitly understood. This will enable future readers to make sure, they don't waste efforts trying the answer in an incorrect version

Comment: @Sven For [mikefarah/yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq), the documentation captures this in [Operators -> Assign -> Update Deeply Selected Results](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/operators/assign-update#update-deeply-selected-results). For [kislyuk/yq](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq), the [jq documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/yq/info) has a section called [Complex Assignments](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Complexassignments).